# django: Cant open two different pages when I have two views for an application

Tags: python, django

I am doing django course from udemy, i did one experiment. Below is my folder structure

```
Project
 appTwo
   urls.py
 ProTwo
   urls.py
```

appTwo/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from appTwo import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.help,name='help'),
    url(r'^$',views.users,name='users'),
]
```

ProTwo/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from appTwo import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^help/',include('appTwo.urls')),
    url(r'^users/',include('appTwo.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Now when i try to open the page users by http://127.0.0.1:8000/users it opens the page help.html. For http://127.0.0.1:8000/help it opens help page. When I comment the first entry in urlpatterns in urls.py it opens the users page even if i try to open help page. Can anyone please guide me what wrong I am doing or its working as expected.

Comment: its better to provide reason for downgrade so that i can take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this. Below two files need to be changed

appTwo/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from appTwo import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^help$',views.help,name='help'),
    url(r'^users$',views.users,name='users'),
]
```

ProTwo/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from appTwo import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^appTwo/',include('appTwo.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

> Explanation:
>   When I type in browser "basic url" i mean the address here it is http://127.0.0.1:8000/, it will go to ProTwo/urls.py which is the project folder. This will open the index page as per line url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'). If you need two configure two different page, give url(r'^appTwo/',include('appTwo.urls')), in the ProTwo/urls.py. This will call appTwo/urls.py. Now for help type http://127.0.0.1:8000/appTwo/help and for users type http://127.0.0.1:8000/appTwo/users.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use different patterns for each View:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^help$', views.help, name='help'),
    url(r'^users$', views.users, name='users'),
]
```

the `name` attribute is only useful for the concept of **reversing**, maybe further in your course?

also, the r'' strings in python are [regular expressions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex), you might want to learn more about them.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying for someone new to python that the django url resolver is using the raw strings as regular expressions, and that the `r` raw string prefix on its own doesn't create a regular expression per se.

Comment: @pablo i tried above code already but getting this error.Using the URLconf defined in ProTwo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='index']
^help/
^users/
admin/
The current path, help, didn't match any of these.